# Reducer for deep state

Tags: react-redux

I have an initial state which looks like this (simplified for the purpose of this question):

```
export default {
  anObject: {
    parameters: {
      param1:'Foo',
      param2:'Bar'
    },
    someOtherProperty:'value'
  }
};
```

And I have a reducer for `anObject` part of which deals with changes to `parameter`. I have an action which passed the `id` of the parameter to change, along with the `newValue` for that parameter. The reducer (again, very slightly simplified) looks like this:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function anObjectReducer(state = initialState.anObject, action){

 switch(action.type){

    case types.UPDATE_PARAMETER:
      return Object.assign(
        {},
        state,
        {
          parameters:Object.assign(
            {},
            state.parameters,
            { [action.id]: action.newValue })
        });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This reducer looks wrong to me. I assumed I would be able to just do it like this:

```
case types.UPDATE_PARAMETER:
    return Object.assign({},state,{parameters:{[action.id]:action.newValue}});
```

But this seems to wipe out all the *other* parameters and just update the single one being changed. Am I missing something obvious about how to structure my reducer?

In case it's relevant this is how I set up my root reducer:

```
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
 import anObject from './anObjectReducer';
 export default combineReducers({
  anObject
 });
```

I thought there might be a way to compose reducers for the individual parts of each object - ie separately for `parameters` and `someOtherProperty` part of `anObject` in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it wipes out other parameters is because you don't pass the previous values in the `Object.assign`.

You should have done that:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  parameters: Object.assign({}, { [action.id]: action.newValue }),
});
```

Or with the ES6 spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
return {
  ...state,
  parameters: {
    ...state.parameters,
    [action.id]: action.newValue,
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had done your first example - it was in the question - but indeed using the spread syntax for objects is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. restructure your reducers: you may use `combineReducers` not for store's root only. This way store stays the same as well as actions but reducers for nested object become lightweight
2. restructure your state(and reducers) to have it as flat as possible. it'd be more efforts needed but typically it also make easier to fetch data in `mapStateToProps`.  [`normalizr`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/README.md) should help to make transition easier by encapsulating integration with existing API that
   requires specific data structure
3. use [`immer`](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) to write code like you're mutating state. This is definitely bad idea if you are learning React, but I'd consider using it on small real projects